# Increasing Size of Company Name in Business Account

Tags: acumatica

Account Name (AccName) in BAccount Table is set as 60 Characters. 
The Company Name can be 255 Characters.

When PXDBString(255) is set for AccName, field size in the Form is extended ! However at the database level it is not changed.

While loading data it gives error - string size...

Is Altering table only column size. Would it cause any issue ??

I have similar problem in Address Line 1, Line 2 and Line 3 as the need is to increase the size from 60 to atleast 100.

Comment: I believe its possible as I have had this question come up before. I dont have a good example handy at the moment but just be aware you might need to also include mods to anything that touches the BAccount table such as customers and vendors.

Comment: I altered the table in the database for the Accname to 255 and Address Columns to 100 and it is working ! But Address is such that it is in various tables and it is required to be altered automatically as Address Copying is done in many Entry Programs.